# how to retrive data from database using mysqli_fetch_array in php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

How can retrive data.here login not working.I used `mysqli_fetch_array`,but before while the condition failed.

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'db.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tbl-login where   username='".$username."'");
$n = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  // $u-id = $row['u-id'];

  $dbusername = $row['username'];
  $dbpassword = $row['password'];
  $usertype = $row['usertype'];
  $_SESSION['usname'] = $dbusername;
  $_SESSION['uid'] = $u-id;
  $_SESSION['usertype'] = $usertype;
  if ($dbusername == $username && $dbpassword == $password) {
    $n++;
    echo "grtet";
    // header('location:dashboard.php');
  }
}

if ($n == 0) {  
  header('location:index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: *but before while the condition failed.* How Did You Know That ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM tbl-login where   username='".$username."' and password='".$password."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query); // Just ONE row, because expecting is, there is only one user with this USERNAME
if(empty($row)) {
    echo 'Invalid username or password';
}else{
    echo 'OK :)';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're not sure what makes a query fail, call [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). While I haven't tested myself, I believe `tbl-login` is the cause of the error (which mysqli_error() should return if you call it).

MySQL allows spaces and non-identifier characters to be table/column name, but when referring to such a name, you need to enclose it between backtick (`` ` ``). Hence `tbl-login` should be written as `` `tbl-login` `` in the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You Have Created table name as `tbl-login`, column name as `u-id` and variable as `$u-id`, which i think is a problem. If Possible, change your column name, table name and variable name. Here are some links to get basic idea for creating variable name, column name, table name.

[Create Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), [Create Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html), [Identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

I've updated your code. Please have a look.

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'db.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_login` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($rowcount > 0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $_SESSION['usname'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['u_id'];
        $_SESSION['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];

         header('location:dashboard.php');
    }

} else {

    header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```